# How to fix the variance between milliseconds and date conversion?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am trying to convert a date to milliseconds then from milliseconds to date in objective c. But variance occurs. I had used the following code.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
    NSDate *dateHolder = [dateFormat dateFromString: @"Nov 25, 2014 4:11:50 PM"];


    NSTimeInterval seconds = [dateHolder timeIntervalSince1970];


   double milliseconds = seconds*1000;
   NSLog(@"Date milliseconds %f", milliseconds);

   NSDate *tr = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: (milliseconds/1000)];
   NSLog(@"Date by milliseconds%@", tr);
```

Output is received as follows

```
 Date milliseconds 1416897710000.000000

 Date by milliseconds 2014-11-25 06:41:50 +0000  // Hours and minutes were varied
```

How to fix ? Thanks in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My output

```
  Date milliseconds 1416913910000.000000
  Date by milliseconds2014-11-25 11:11:50 +0000
```

Maybe because of the Time Difference ?